# Only display value of text_field if @search is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an search form, for my Search model. My problem is that i only want to display the value of the form if @search is present. I wrote this code:

```
 <%= f.text_field :keyword, :value => @search.keyword if @search.present? %>
```

My problem is that when @search is not present the whole form is not displayed! I only want that the value is not displayed in this case!

UPDATE UPDATE:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I wrote an little helper:

```
def value(link)
 if @search.present?
  value: @search.link
 end
end
```

And in my form:

```
<%= f.text_field :keyword, value(keyword) %>
```

But why do i get this error:

```
s_helper.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end value: @search.link
```

Comment: what actually is @search?

Comment: @search = Search.find(params[:id]) Does this matter?

Comment: <% if @search.present? %> <%= f.text_field :keyword, :value => @search.keyword %> <% end %> would work but I think there might be a more idiomatic way to write this.

Comment: Yes! I have the same feeling! The thing is i have many text fields that should dispaly an value if @search is present!

Comment: I think you didnt understand me correclty! I only want not to show the value it @search is not present

Comment: `<%= f.text_field :keyword, :value => @search.present? ? @search.keyword : '' %>`

Comment: Do you want the keyword value to be shown if `@search` is present or not present? If it should be shown if `@search` is present then my code above is correct, else change the `if` to `unless.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, if there's no @search, you still want the empty input to appear. If so, this should do what you want:

```
  <%= f.text_field :keyword, :value => @search.try(:keyword) %>
```

See this article for info about the try method -http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! But why does my helper method not work? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.text_field :keyword, :value => @search.keyword %> <% if @search.present? %>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have something like this.

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
```

Change it to

```
<%= form_for (@search || Search.new) do |f| %>
```

and than remove all the `@search...` stuff from the form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `present?` method provided through Rails API,

```
<% if @search.present? %>
  <%= f.text_field :keyword, :value => @search.keyword %>
<% end %>
```

Refer [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present?) for more information.